# Change default app for file extension

Tags: macos, high-sierra

I just set up default app for certain file extension by mistake. Now i cannot revert it back to default, i can only set another app to open this type of file (CMD+I).

I've tried to rebuild LaunchServices then reboot, but nothing changed. I still can open .twig files with SublimeText 3

Comment: Whatever you have chosen is the default app. Just change it back to whichever app it was before you changed it.

Comment: @l008com, it had no app associated with it. Cannot return to that state

Comment: What OS? [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) can remove file associations, but I understand it no longer runs on High Sierra.

Comment: High Sierra, ofc. Yes, RCDefault not working anymore.

Comment: then maybe [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps)

Comment: @Tetsujin, https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps/issues/3

Comment: out of luck then, I guess.

Comment: Don't u know how to that with terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Duti sets associations, see https://github.com/moretension/duti/ or if you use Homebrew simply `brew install duti` then follow the included instructions.

Comment: duti is not a homebrew app - it is a generic commandline app. Also how does it set the default to no app

Comment: Editors and reviewers  please take care. It nedd editig but you removed the important point that it does not work.